# Is there a Prestashop add-on to allow my customers to upload their own code and sell it?

Tags: web-applications, prestashop, file-sharing

I would like to create a webpage where my customers can upload their own source code and sell it, so that I will take a percentage of that sale as commission. Is there a way to do this with Prestashop? Thank you very much your support  :) !

Regards,
Emilio

Comment: on which sleepers of prestashop you have to work ?

Comment: Search for "marketplaces" addons for PrestaShop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but it is not a quick job.
To solve your problem as painless choice would be to give a very restricted access to the BE.

I would think the development of this app i this way:

- First of all you should create a profile type appropriate to your idea.
- I would create FrontEmployeesController.php as inspiration: AdminEmployeesController and creating its TPL.
- This controller can force entering the Traveller's new user profile you created earlier.
- In AdminProductsController.php you may block the entry of non-virtual products.